# How to efficiently fill-in a structure with vectors?

Tags: c++

I am not expert in C++ but I believe this is not the most elegant solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct coord {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{ std::vector<int> a {1,2,3,4,5};
  std::vector<int> b {10,20,30,40,50};
  int i;
  std::vector<coord> loc (5);
  for (i=0;i<5;i++)
  { loc[i].x = a[i];
    loc[i].y = b[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Does anyone has a better solution ?

Comment: Look at the Boost "zip iterator".

Comment: One thing I would do differently (and this is really a minor thing), is to declare the `i` inside the for like so: `for(int i=0; i<loc.size(); ++i)`. Also using `size()` avoids bugs if you change the number of elements.

Comment: The first thing to note is that `a` and `b` are pointless. Instead, use `= i` and `= i * 10`.

Comment: @Borgleader: and make it the same type as `log.size()` obviously...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using C++11. While I'm not 100% sure this should work:

```
std::vector<coord> loc { {1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}, {4, 40}, {5, 50} };
```

Comment: Ok it does it but as mentioned in my comment below, the example is a simplification of my real problem. The question is really how to fill-in a structure with vectors and not how to fill in a structure by hand. Sorry if the question was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish by creating two vectors just to fill one vector? Your method is inefficient when it comes to declaring two independent vectors to assign into one single vector, and also messy. Remove the two vectors and set the values of your vector using brackets

---

`= { {val1,val2} {val1,val2} {val1,val2} }`

But if you would like to stick with your vector filling method and HAVE to use a vector, just one one vector that holds both the values of a and b and loop as such

```
//check to make sure size is even
for(int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i +=2)
{
    vect[i].x = a[i];
    vect[i].y = a[i+1];
}
```

Comment: For the example here the vectors have been filled-in by hand to simplify things. Actually, I am dealing with a bigger program in which I have 2 vectors I wish to put in a structure.